# Adding a column using the urllib.parse

Tags: python, parsing, url

I have a CSV imported using Pandas :

```
df = pd.read_csv('files_2.csv')
```

One of the columns in the data is PAGE URL , I would like to add a column to the data frame with functions executed using the urlib

something like this:

```
o = urlparse(df['Page URL'])
o.query #function that pull the data 
parse_qs(o.query) # the logic for the column
```

The new column should hold the results from the parse_qs(o.query) function. I am new to using Python 3 and it will be great if you can point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: You want the entire contents of the data to be in the corresponding cells of that column?

Comment: The new column should hold the results from parse_qs(o.query)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
page_url = urlparse(df['Page URL'])
df['query'] = parse_qs(page_url.query)
```

Remember that `parse_qs()` returns a dictionary, so you will have dictionaries in your `query` cells.

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: The first line page_url = urlparse(df['Page URL'])

Comment: @sai Try using `apply()` method as mentioned by @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
df = pd.DataFrame({"Page URL": ["https://www.google.com/search?ei=0kkkk"]})
df['query'] = df['Page URL'].apply(urlparse).apply(lambda x: parse_qs(x.query))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                 Page URL                query
0  https://www.google.com/search?ei=0kkkk  {u'ei': [u'0kkkk']}
```